# how to run cmd command of change directory using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I command "cd C:/Users/Mansi/Downloads/ConfuserEx-CLI" and "Confuser.CLI.exe C:\Users\Mansi\Desktop\pr1.crproj" in c# code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands this may help you.

Comment: Minor detail: do you really need to set the WorkingDirectory to that folder, or just start the exe that is in that folder?